# Z3 makefile does not recognize file change

Tags: makefile, z3, recompile

I'm using z3 quite a lot, but now is the first time I need to actually change some files and rebuild with my changes. I built z3 initially just like the instructions [here](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3), brought here again for completeness:

```
git clone https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3.git
cd z3
python scripts/mk_make.py -d
cd build
make -j 4
sudo make install
```

When I changed some files I naively navigated to `z3/build` and ran `make`.
This is the message I got and **nothing was recompiled**:

```
Z3 was successfully built.
Z3Py scripts can already be executed in the 'build/python' directory.
Z3Py scripts stored in arbitrary directories can be executed if the 'build/python' directory is added to the PYTHONPATH environment variable and the 'build' directory is added to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable.
Use the following command to install Z3 at prefix /usr.
    sudo make install
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue. What files did you alter?

Comment: @PatrickTrentin z3/src/api/c++/z3++.h

Comment: The issue seems to be specific for that, and possibly some other, header files, so I would suggest you to include such list in your question.

Comment: Z3 itself doesn't use `z3++.h`, it's the C++ API that's used by applications and the C++ example. If I remember correctly, just calling `make` won't rebuild the examples, try `make examples` to see whether it picks up your changes.